# TCP layer behaviour upon receiving wrong sequence number

Tags: tcp, networking

I have the IP and port details of an already established connection between the TCP server and the client. As I am simulating packet injection attack using the **packETH** tool, I disguise my self as the client(using client's IP and port, but not same seq and ack numbers) and send FIN segment, then I expect connection close or some abnormal behavior, but it isn't happening.
My question is, what might exactly be happening? and what happens if I send a repeated SYN segment.

Comment: Can I suggest you post some packet traces?

Comment: The server will not accept the FIN segment (or any other) if it does not hold a sequence number inside the server current window.

Comment: "_between the TCP server and the client._" TCP does not have servers or clients. The client/server concept is an application-layer (off-topic) concept. TCP creates connections between peers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try it with the RST bit set.  Your SEQ/ACK shouldn't matter in that case.  If that doesn't work it is probably because you messed up your checksum and the packet is getting dropped.